# django - adding user ID to UpdateView

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a few UpdateViews that are using ModelForms. Each object has a foreign key to User so I can keep each user's data separate. When I try to update data on the form, I get:

> AttributeError at /finances/transaction/update/4
>   'module' object has no attribute 'user'

Creating the object works just fine. It's the update that gives me the error.

One such model and view looks like this:

```
# Model
class Transaction(models.Model):
    item_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    payment_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PAYMENT_CHOICES, verbose_name="Payment Type")
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="Estimated Amount")
    actual_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="Actual Amount")
    due_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Due Date")
    is_credit = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Is Asset")
    is_paid = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Paid/Received?")
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

#ModelForm
class TransactionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ['is_paid', 'item_description', 'due_date', 'amount', 'actual_amount', 'is_credit', 'account',]

#View
class TransactionUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Transaction
    form_class = TransactionForm
    template_name = 'finances/transaction_update.html'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        transaction = form.save(commit=False)
        transaction.user = self.request.user
        transaction.save()
        return super(TransactionUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's initializing property. Try to change the `__init__()` method -

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.kwargs = kwargs
    return super(TransactionUpdate, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```